# "Three pieces of email" alternately to "three emails" in AE?

Tags: american-english, word-usage, uncountable-nouns

Does American English allow the use of "email" as a mass noun, in such a way that it is not uncommon to hear any such of the following phrases from native speakers?

*I've still got a huge **backload of email** I'm trying to get through.*

*I've forwarded without comment **a couple of pieces of email** that I received overnight.*

*There's **one last piece of email** to read.*

*On average, three to **six pieces of email** are returned to the library every week.*

*Billions and **billions of pieces of email** are transmitted daily.*

***How much email*** do you have in your inbox?

*Are you sending too much or **too little email** to prospects?*

Comment: Usage as mass noun is indeed current, especially in the phrase "check my e[-]mail." Your first example and your last two would pass current, I think. The ones containing the expression *piece[s] of email,* however, are less likely, since the option to use the term as a count noun is in those cases more economical.

Comment: Ngram suggests that ***email*** is used as an uncountable noun. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=piece+of+email%2Cpieces+of+email%2Cmuch+email%2C+little+email&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpiece%20of%20email%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpieces%20of%20email%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmuch%20email%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clittle%20email%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Yes, some individuals use *email* exclusively as a mass noun, never as a count noun.

Comment: I've never heard anyone say pieces of email...never.

Comment: I have heard just about every variation possible.  "Email" can be treated as countable or uncountable (though some contexts will "prefer" one or the other).

Comment: @Josh61 - the OP is asking how AE uses it. "Emails" is fine. Most likely the dictionary hasn't caught up yet.

Comment: "Have you gotten (remember, this is AmE) my emails?" is the most common way of phrasing this question. (Well, maybe outnumbered by "Did you get my emails?") Reply: "What emails?" Response: "I sent you three emails about it! Don't you ever check your *email*?" R: Sure, I check **it** every day!" R: "Well, you should have seen **them** then!" (And, because AmE) R: "Why of course, you're right. My sincere apologies. Let me double-check that directly!"

Comment: @medica, OK, I'll bite: what would BrE substitute for that last speech in this exchange?

Comment: I always use _email_ as a mass noun, and refer to individual instances as **an email message**.  As the word _email_ is analogous to "mail", I don't use it in the plural.  If you wouldn't say  "I {received/sent} four mails today.", why would you say "I {received/sent} four emails today."?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock I think medica is saying "Have you gotten my emails?" is AmEng. In BrEng it would be: "Have you got my email(s)?" (*and* "Did you get my emails?")

Comment: I think it a shame that some users have chosen to delete Rathony's answer. It expressed a viewpoint, however erroneous, that many users and speakers might share. It's GOOD to hear different sides of any argument, as long as the discussion is civil and rational.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Indeed. As long as the discussion is rational...and civil.

Comment: @marylou: but that's not what this question is about. And my comment was not directed at Medica (as you might notice, I fidn't mention the words _get, got, or gotten_.  But now that you mention it, I'm surprised, Medica, that anyone would seriously think that a typical AmE response might be "My sincere apologies. Let me double-check that directly!  (That was tongue-in-cheek, was it not, Medica? If I heard that in California, I would take it as heavy sarcasm.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(AE "allows" anything you like.)

The question is whether an AE speaker understands this or that, or perhaps whether most AE speakers understand it, or perhaps whether some or many or most use it when speaking.

And yes, *email* is used as both a countable noun and a collective noun. Both *too much email* and *three emails* (or *three mails* or *three messages*) are used. It is not uncommon to hear it used in any of these ways.

---

To satisfy @JanusBahsJacquet and anyone else who might be in doubt: If someone said "*pieces of email*" s?he would be understood, but a native speaker would be unlikely to use that phrase. It is, in particular, the "*pieces*" that is unusual. "*Messages of email*" would pass (though it is a bit redundant).  Even "*items of email*" might pass.

But when referring to individual instances, we generally use *email* (or *message* or *mail*) itself, as a countable noun. Simpler.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by mentioning that, despite e-mail being able to act both as countable and uncountable, _piece(s) of e-mail_ is not commonly heard.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I thought that went without saying, especially as it had already been mentioned. What I said was that "*it is not uncommon to hear it used* **in any of these ways**", by which I meant the ways that I mentioned (not any of the ways listed in the question).

Comment: Always best to assume nothing goes without saying (especially because it had only been mentioned in comments, which are subject to deletion without warning, so if someone who sees the page in six months’ time, there may not be any mention of it at all). :-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: OK, I mentioned it.

Comment: There's a tiny typo in your otherwise fine answer: s?he

Comment: @Mari-LouA: **`*s?he*`** is a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) that stands for either "*she*" or "*he*". It matches "*he*", perhaps preceded by "*s*".

Comment: I've never seen it written like that. I've seen: S/he; she or he; and (s)he.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: It's not English (yet). It's nerd-write, I guess. But then, I'm not sure whether "*s/he*" is English -- dunno how either of these two might be pronounced. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

"Three pieces of email" conveys a slightly different message from "three emails".

If you ask me when I'm going to be free for lunch and I reply "I've got three pieces of email to check first", this implies that they are generic emails, and I likely don't even know what the subjects are.  "I've got three emails to check first", on the other hand, implies that I likely have at least looked at their subject lines already.

In the first case odds are reasonably good that the three are all junk or, at the very least, somehow deferrable, so it will only take a couple of minutes.

In the second case, since I've likely looked at them already, I know that they're not junk, and there's a chance that some will take at least several minutes to respond to or otherwise handle.  It could be a half hour or more before I'm free for lunch.

These are the sort of subtle clues that one misses when looking only at the literal definitions and equivalences of words, believing that one can be freely substituted for another.